How to get a list of similar cases using Einstein prompt builder?
The company I work for has some Einstein for Service Add-on licences. I am trying to get some useful information using the Einstein prompt builder, but the results are deeply disappointing. I have experience with ChatGPT and CodePilot and the results from Einstein prompt builder are underwhelming.
Example. We get a lot of similar cases-by-email, so I made this prompt:

What cases look like case number 45890?

Einstein returned this exact case.
Next prompt:

yes, that is the case I am talking about. What other cases are there
that are similar to this one?

Reply:

It seems that the query returned the same case again. To find similar
cases, I will need to refine the search criteria. Could you provide
more details on what makes this case unique or specify the criteria
for similarity (e.g., subject, status, priority)?

Me again:

which cases have a subject that looks like the subject from case
45890?

Reply:

Here is the case with a subject similar to the one from case number
45890. How else can I assist you?

And then it shows case 45890.
Knowing what ChatGPT and CodePilot are capable of, this is very disappointing. Any tips on how to get the data that I want from Einstein?
